# Show custom icon on a folder icon

Tags: windows, icons

There are lots references to completely changing a specific folder's icon with a custom one (Properties | Customize | Change icon).  What I want is, for a specific folder, embed a custom icon onto the default folder icon so that the end-user still knows that it is a folder.  The desired effect is similar to the system folders, like Documents, Pictures etc. shown here:

[image]

Here is a mock-up of what I am after:

[image]

This is for Windows 10 but I am hoping that it is possible to do this in Windows 7+.

Update: I am not looking for a programmatic solution or one that affects all folders that meet a certain requirement.  Rather, similar to how it is possible to completely change one specific folder's icon, I want to do that for a specific icon but keep the folder icon too.

Comment: [Overlay icons in Windows](//stackoverflow.com/q/5381207)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe those two solutions are for when you want all folders--or at least several folders--to show an overlay icon.  I don't think this is an overlay in the same sense that TortoiseSVN is, for instance.  The change should apply to one specific folder.